# Send an email through SMTP using different public IP

Tags: ruby, smtp

Assuming my server has 2 public IPs, what are the steps in Ruby to send an email through SMTP protocol using the first IP and then using the second IP?

I'm aware of the TCPSocket option to specify `local_host` option, however I can't find anything similar for SMTP and I can't find any option for the constructor accepting the already built socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the source code for the Net::SMTP class in the Ruby Standard Library, the class has a private [`tcp_socket`](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-net-smtp/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/net/smtp/smtp.rb#L539-L541) method that creates a new socket:

```
def tcp_socket(address, port)
  TCPSocket.open address, port
end
```

You could subclass `Net::SMTP` and override that method to return something else, or just monkey-patch it if you need something quick-and-dirty.

Note that setting the `@socket` instance_variable directly (using `instance_variable_set`) is *not* going to work; despite the name, this instance variable doesn't hold a plain Socket instance, it holds a wrapper object of class `Net::InternetMessageIO`, which itself may be wrapping an `OpenSSL::SSL::Socket` object, which in turn wraps a real `TCPSocket` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found the following: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html#class-Net::SMTP-label-HELO+domain would this do the trick? It looks like you can actually set the ip address through the HELO domain, but based on the source you linked, is only used to declare the domain you are from, not to actually use the specified IP

Comment: Yeah, based on my understanding the HELO domain is more about a notional "where is this message from?" question, and has nothing to do with a transport-layer question like "which network interface should I transmit these packets on?" That said, you could certainly try it and see.